# Fill input tag that has no name with python

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I'm trying to fill in an input tag with python with mechanicalsoup but it has no name field and I can't find a way to fill it with mechanicalsoup, does anybody have a workaround or another library that would allow me to do so ?

(the actual input):

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Comment: It has an ID, you can find it using that.

Comment: @Barmar how ? I searched how I could do it by input but found no documentation about it

Comment: @MatthieuMoy thanks ! I'll look into it, I searched quite a bit but probably missed it because of the w/o in the title